# gcc - compile x386 assembly code error

Tags: c++, c, gcc

when I use 'gcc -m32 -o stack temp.s' to compile my x86 assembly code, I got errors as below:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think it's because of lack of 32-bit lib, but I dont know how to install it...
Thank you...

Comment: Sorry for being "that guy", but you probably mean x86 or i386. i386 is the short name of the first 32-bit Intel CPU; x86 refers to the family of instruction sets that Intel 8086-compatible CPUs (which originally all had names finishing with "86") support. x386 isn't an instruction set or a CPU.

Comment: @zneak I didn't know well this before. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar issue and I solved as follows:

```
apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. But It just compile successfully, Is there any way to run it on my machine?